# achartengine LineGraph import int from sql

Tags: android, sql, database, achartengine, linegraph

I'm making a LineGraph class using achartengine. The problem is that I'm not able to import data from the database. I want to add two int database columns into int series. How do I do that? This is what I have so far:

```
package com.weightmaster.awesome.development.chart;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;

import com.weightmaster.awesome.development.WeightMasterOverviewActivity;
import com.weightmaster.awesome.development.database.WMSQLiteHelper;

public class LineGraph {


public static SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;
public static WMSQLiteHelper helper;

public static XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset(String title) {

    Log.d(WeightMasterOverviewActivity.TAG, "Kjører metoden1");

    Cursor cursor = helper.getDateAsc();
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1");
    TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries(title);

    Log.d(WeightMasterOverviewActivity.TAG, "Kjører metoden");
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.d(WeightMasterOverviewActivity.TAG,
            "Cursoren flyttet til første element");
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        int date = cursor.getInt((Integer) cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
        Log.d(WeightMasterOverviewActivity.TAG, "Legger til dato");

        int weight = cursor.getInt((Integer) cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("weight"));
        Log.d(WeightMasterOverviewActivity.TAG, "Legger til vekt");
        series2.add(weight, date);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        Log.d(WeightMasterOverviewActivity.TAG,
                "Cursoren flyttet til neste element");
    }
    Log.d(WeightMasterOverviewActivity.TAG,
            "There were no values in the cursor.");
    cursor.close();

    Log.d(WeightMasterOverviewActivity.TAG, "Den når til enden");
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    dataset.addSeries(series2);

    return dataset;
}

public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

    //Lager TimeSeries for den første linja


    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = getDemoDataset("Line1");

    //Kode for render
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    //Optimalisering linje1
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);

    // Optimalisering linje2 husk rekke følgen
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

    //Legger til render seriene
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    //Optimalisering grafen
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Test");
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Dager");
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);


    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, 
            mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");

    return intent;

}
}
```

It stops at the following line in the debuger:

```
Cursor cursor = helper.getDateAsc();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to make a new WMSQLiteHelper. Right now it's null.  I don't know what the parameters are for your helper but it should look like something like this.

```
helper = new WMSQLiteHelper(this);
```

put it right above

```
Cursor cursor = helper.getDateAsc();
```

Comment: I think this is what I need, but I dont `extend activity` so I can't use `this`. What do I use instead?